# How to normalize weights of a fully connected layer in the caffe prototxt file?

Tags: neural-network, caffe

I would like to implement the COCO loss described in this [paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/1702.06890.pdf) (see Eq. **7**). This requires providing the unit norm of the features **f** and weights **c**. I can normalize the features. However, do not know how to normalize weights **c**.

Can anyone please tell me if I can access the weights within the caffe prototxt file and normalize it?

Comment: Do you mean by changing the prototxt file or by loading the model, then normalizing the innerproduct weights and saving them? The first one is probably not possible

Comment: Writing directly in the prototxt file to normalize weights of the FC layer. No pre-trained model will be loaded. Can we access the weights and modify them directly in the prototxt file?

Comment: Either way after initializing model weights you can to loop through the FC layers and normalize the blobs using C++ api. I am not sure about in python.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Will try to do this. Then it seems the answer to my question is - "within caffe prototxt file it is impossible".